# Problema con número de pasos de persistencia multiplicativa

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Números persistentes

> En *El prodigio de los números* de Clifford A. Pickover, cap. 15, aparece un ejemplo de serie numérica:
> 969, 486, 192, 18, 8. Cada número se calcula multiplicando los dígitos del anterior.

A partir de este ejemplo me piden definir el concepto de persistencia de un número como el número de pasos del tipo referido que hay que llevar a cabo antes de que el número colapse bajo la forma de un único dígito.

En el ejemplo:

- Paso 1: 969, 9*6*9
- Paso 2: 486, 4*8*6
- Paso 3: 192, 1*9*2
- Paso 4: 18, 1*8

El paso 5 no se cuenta ya que me piden los pasos que hay que llevar a cabo antes de que el número colapse bajo la forma de un único dígito.

Me piden definir una función `primer_persistente(n)` que devuelva los pasos como tal y el número de pasos .

> Nota: Puede usarse enumeración exhaustiva, puesto que el valor de `n` será relativamente bajo. Así, por ejemplo, no se conoce números con persistencia 12 o superior.

**Mi problema es que no he conseguido implementar un contador de los pasos sin que me devuelva error.**

**A ver si podeís ayudarme.**
***Gracias de antemano.***

Esto es lo que llevo:

```py
# Numeros persistentes

from math import prod

n = int(input("Introduce un numero entero: "))
print(n)

def primer_persistente(n):
    digitos = [int(i) for i in str(n)] # Lista con los digitos separados 
    persistencia = [prod(digitos)] # Lista con el producto de todos los digitos

    if len(digitos) != len(persistencia):
        print(persistencia[0])
        primer_persistente(persistencia[0])

primer_persistente(n)
```

> Output

```
Introduce un numero entero: 969
969
486
192
18
8
```

> La salida que estoy buscando es la siguiente:

```
Introduce un numero entero: 969
969
486
192
18
8

Los pasos que se han llevado a cabo son: 4
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No necesitamos recursión, basta con un ciclo repetitivo llevando un contador.

El ciclo se repite mientras `n` sea mayor que 9, o sea, mientras tenga más de un digito. La variable `contador` lleva la cuenta de cuantas veces hemos iterado en el ciclo.

Agregue un `return` para devolver el número de pasos realizados:

```
n = int(input("Introduce un numero entero: "))

def primer_persistente(n):
    contador = 0
    while n > 9:
        print(f"persistencia {n}")
        contador += 1
        digitos = [int(i) for i in str(n)] # Lista con los digitos separados
        n = prod(digitos) 
    print(f"persistencia {n}")

    return contador

cuenta = primer_persistente(n)
print(f"Los pasos llevados a cabo son {cuenta}")
```

**Validación**

```
Introduce un numero entero: 969
persistencia 969
persistencia 486
persistencia 192
persistencia 18
persistencia 8
Los pasos llevados a cabo son 4
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si la solución ha de ser necesariamente utilizando recursividad, tu contador debe ser incrementado también de forma recursiva.

Esto implica que la función `primer_persistente()` debe retornar como resultado el valor del contador. Este contador tendrá el valor 0 en el caso en que el parámetro recibido tenga un dígito de longitud. En cualquier otro caso el contador será 1 + el número de pasos requerido para el producto (el cual se obtiene con llamada recursiva).

Por otro lado, en tu código usas una forma bien curiosa de mirar si el número recibido tiene longitud 1, puesto que usas:

```
if len(digitos) != len(persistencia):
```

cuando simplemente podrías usar:

```
if len(digitos) != 1:
```

ya que la lista `persistencia` que usas para almacenar el producto sólo tiene un elemento siempre. Y de hecho tal lista es completamente supérflua.

Juntando esta observación con lo antes dicho sobre el contador recursivo, la cosa quedaría así:

```
from math import prod

n = int(input("Introduce un numero entero: "))
print(n)

def primer_persistente(n):
    digitos = [int(i) for i in str(n)] # Lista con los digitos separados
    persistencia = prod(digitos) # Producto de todos los digitos

    if len(digitos) != 1:
        print(persistencia)
        return 1 + primer_persistente(persistencia)
    else:
        return 0

pasos = primer_persistente(n)
print("Los pasos que se han llevado a cabo son:", pasos)
```

La función se puede simplificar ligeramente mirando nada más empezar si ya hay que retornar 0, o calculando el producto y la llamada recursiva si no:

```
def primer_persistente(n):
    if len(str(n)) == 1:
        return 0

    digitos = [int(i) for i in str(n)] # Lista con los digitos separados
    persistencia = prod(digitos) # producto de todos los digitos
    print(persistencia)
    return 1 + primer_persistente(persistencia)
```